# Filter list of objects depending on the field of another object list

Tags: java, arraylist, java-6

Using Java 6, how is the better way to know if a list of objects contains a field of another list of objects?

I have implemented it using two `for` but I do not know if this affects to performance. Is there any Java feature like `streams` in Java 8?

```
public class Object1 {
    private BigDecimal field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
}
public class Object2 {
    private BigDecimal field1;
    private String field2;
}

List<Object1> list1 = new ArrayList<Object1>();
List<Object2> list2 = new ArrayList<Object2>();
List<Object1> listFilter = new ArrayList<Object1>();
for (Object object1 : list1) {
    for (Object object2 : list2) {
        if(object1.getField1().compareTo(object2.getField1())==0) {
            listFilter.add(object1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Using Java 6"_ -- why are you using a Java version that is long past end-of-life?

Comment: Customer requirement... @JimGarrison

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
for (Object object1 : list1) {
    for (Object object2 : list2) {
        if(object1.getField1().compareTo(object2.getField1())==0) {
            listFilter.add(object1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)*** time complexity.  You should put the `Object2.field1` values into a `Set<?>` first, then checking for existence is ***O(n)***

```
// Build a Set of unique Object2.field1 values
Set<BigDecimal> o2f1set = new HashSet<BigDecimal>();
for (Object2 o2 : list2)
    o2f1Set.add(o2.getField1);

// Select Object1 instances whose field1 value matches any
// field1 value that was in list2
for (Object1 o1 : list1)
    if (o2f1Set.contains(o1.getField1())
        listFilter.add(o1);
```

This of course assumes that the class of `field1` properly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, which `BigDecimal` does.

If the range of possible `field1` values is integer, strongly bounded and relatively small (i.e. your requirements and model limit the values to a range, say `0..1000`), you could optimize this by using a `boolean` array instead of a set. In those highly limited circumstances this would improve performance even more.

Comment: I have defined the type of flied1 as BigDecimal in my question